# Modeling workflow for symmetrical indented plane

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

I'm fairly new to blender and don't have a good overlook of what can be done with the modifiers yet. Currently I have a plane with a more or less centered ridge, now I wanted to make an X-crossing by copying that plane, turning it around 90 degrees and somehow combining it with the first one. However it don't find a way to do this.

Basically, I'm looking for function that aligns an object to the axis minima of 2 other objects. Or any other way to accomplish this.

Okay, here are some pictures to better show what I would like to acquire.

Assume I have a plane like this:
[image: basic plane with a rift]

Now I copy this plane and rotate it around 90 degrees around the Z axis. The result looks like this from above:
[image: both planes from above]
And like this from below:
[image: both planes from below]

These two planes are joint to get a single object. Now what I would like to have is something like this:
[image: The result]

This was done creating a second plane with a higher vertex count and using shrinkwrap. However, the curves in the "rift" are a bit smoothed and not as sharp as in the combined origin mesh. When I use projection for shrinkwrap I get artifacts.

This was the best I was able to get. Is there a more simple method and/or a method which is more exact, meaning I get the sharp corners where the "rifts" are crossing?

Comment: I'm unsure about what the axis minima criterion means but you can join ( or intersect or difference ) your two ridge planes using the BoolTool. Here's a video describing the tool: [How to Use The BoolTool in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZ6_5jtn0G8)

Answer (score 3):

starting with two objects like you describe:
[image]

Add a shrinkwrap modifier

[image]

to get something like this:

[image]

Some faces look beveled because the quads forming the mesh cannot accommodate the deformation properly.

To correct the topology of the edges in question, there are two options:

- 1: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate the mesh.

[image]

- 2: Manually subdivide the offending faces selecting vertices and using <kbd>J</kbd> to join the edges.

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an Array modifier to your plane
2. Add an Empty to your scene
3. Set the Object Offset of the modifier to the new Empty:
4. Move the Emtpy up along Z, and rotate it 90 degrees.

[image]

Of course, you'll have to manually move the Empty up and down until it looks good.. I'm not sure how you could automatically detect the amount of offset required.

When you click "Apply" on the Array modifier, both planes will exist as a single object.

Comment: Actually, I think this isn't quite what you want... I'll wait until you update your question before making any edits.

Comment: I'm terrible sorry for the lack of updates, life's been harsh and I didn't have much time. However, that's almost what I intended to do. Just imagine that the upper plane is "pushed" into the lower one and as a result I would get a plane that has a "cross rift".

Comment: for some time I was wondering if that would be possible by aligning these two planes on the z axis and then use a third plane with shrink-wrap to get my intended result. But I hadn't had any time to test that